# Can we make a question with inversion sentence?

Tags: questions, inversion

In an essay, can I write the next question about free time? Is is grammatically correct?

> Seldom have I watched films on TV?

Comment: What is the situation where someone would ask this? What would they be trying to express?

Answer (score 1):

No, that does not parse as a question, because *seldom* is one of the (negative polarity) words which, if it comes first in a sentence, triggers inversion.

So

> Seldom have I watched television.

is a statement, not a question.

(Other examples are *never*, *nowhere*, *rarely*).

If *seldom* doesn't come first, then it would be a question:

> Have I seldom watched television?

though that is an odd question to ask, and reads as a rhetorical question (one that is not really expecting an answer). Perhaps that's what you meant.

Comment: I don't know why someone *downvoted* this. It's obviously correct, and more succinctly expressed than I could have done. It seems to me this particular "inversion" is (almost?) always a bit stylised / poetic / literary, but somehow this aspect seems less noticeable if the "left-promoted" adverbial element is longer: *Not once in all of the forty years I've lived here **have I spoken** to my neighbour, Never in all my life **have I heard** such nonsense!*